# Error: Unexpected value 'ProductService' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, http, observable, observablecollection, subscribe

i am attempting to perform an http call via observables in the "ProductService.ts", imported into the "ProductComponent.ts" which suscribes to it. I think I have covered everything required however I am getting following the error:

Error: Unexpected value 'ProductService' declared by the module 'AppModule'.

Please can someone point out where I am going wrong?

AppModule:

```
/* angular */
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";

/* third party */ 
import { TooltipModule } from "ngx-tooltip";
import { NgRedux, NgReduxModule } from 'ng2-redux';
import { Ng2Bs3ModalModule } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';
import { RootReducer, IAppStore } from './state/state.store'; 

/* components */
import { BaseComponent } from './base.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './includes/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './includes/footer.component';
import { NavigationComponent } from './includes/navigation.component';
import { MapComponent } from './components/maps/map.component';
import { ToolbarComponent } from './components/ui/toolbar/toolbar.component';
import { SearchComponent } from './components/ui/search/search.component';
import { StoreComponent } from './state/state.component';
import { ModalComponent } from './components/ui/modal/modal.component';
import { UserComponent } from './components/users/user.component';
import { CategoryComponent } from './services/products/category.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './services/products/product.component';
import { ProductDetails } from './services/products/productdetails.component';
import { CartComponent } from './services/cart/cart.component';
import { CheckoutComponent } from './services/checkout/checkout.component';
import { NotificationComponent } from './components/ui/notifications/notification.component';
import { PanelComponent } from './components/ui/panel/panel.component';
import { UIController } from './components/ui/uinav/uicontroller.component';
import { ProductService } from './services/products/product.service';

/* views */
import { HomeComponent } from './views/home.view';
import { ContactComponent } from './views/contact.view';
import { AboutComponent } from './views/about.view';
import { MainComponent } from './views/main.view';
import { FormsComponent } from './views/forms.view';
import { PlansView } from './views/plans.view';
import { ProductView } from './views/products.view';

/* routers */
import { routing } from './routers/routing.route'; 

/* custom */
import { ScrollTo } from './helpers/ScrollCtrl';
import { MenuCtrl } from './helpers/MenuCtrl';

@NgModule({ 
  declarations: [
    BaseComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    FormsComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    NavigationComponent,
    MainComponent,
    MapComponent,
    ModalComponent,
    ToolbarComponent,
    StoreComponent,
    UserComponent,
    CategoryComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    ProductDetails,
    CartComponent,
    CheckoutComponent,
    SearchComponent,
    NotificationComponent,
    PanelComponent,
    ProductView,
    PlansView,
    UIController,
    ProductService
  ],
  exports:[
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    NgReduxModule,
    Ng2Bs3ModalModule,
    TooltipModule 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [
    BaseComponent
  ]
}) 

export class AppModule {
  constructor(ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppStore>) {
    ngRedux.configureStore(RootReducer, {
      appState: null
    });
  }
}
```

ProductComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from './product.entity';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';
import { ProductCategory } from './productcategory.entity';

@Component({
    selector: 'e-productlist',
    templateUrl: './templates/products.template.html'    
})

export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
    public productList: Product[];

    constructor(private _productService: ProductService) {  
    }

    ngOnInit(){ 
        this._productService.GetAllProducts().subscribe(response => this.productList);
    } 
}
```

ProductService.ts

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Product } from './product.entity';
    import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
    import { ProductCategory } from './productcategory.entity';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Injectable()
    export class ProductService implements IProductService {
        private productCategories: ProductCategory[];
        private products: Product[];
        private queryUrl = "../../../products-list.json";

        constructor(public _http: Http) {  
        }

        GetAllProducts() { 
            return this._http.get(this.queryUrl).map((_response:Response) => this.products = _response.json()); 
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't declare services. You provide them. Move it from declarations to providers and that should clean it up (that is, as long as your service is otherwise all sorted out and correct etc).

Comment: You are genius... that solved it. Thanks for the swift response.

Comment: The whole "what is providers, what is declarations, what is imports, why import at top and imports again in the API, what is exports, how is this exports different from a class exports..." thing is a never ending source of confusion and something I think they could simplify or at least make clearer. You eventually get it, but it's confusing as hell to get rolling.

Comment: Yes they should make it clearer, its a shame one has to deal with the error to "get it". Thanks for the quick response, sorted out my headache.